# How to acces selfi camera with kivy

Tags: python, kivy, android-camera, buildozer

I was playing with the exemple camera app from kivy website, but I have encounter a probleme.

(link for the kivy code : https://kivy.org/doc/stable/examples/gen__camera__main__py.html )

I have a Mi9 SE, and so I have 4 camera on my phone.

When using the "index: 0" every worked perfecly.

I wanted to acces te selfi camera, but here the problems begin.

I have try index from 1 to 6 and every time I have an "resolution" error.

The index -1 give me nothing the app dosen't crash but no player start.

I've also try reolution (320,240) didin't change the result.

If you have any clue on how to have acces to the seflie camera, I will be grateful for your anser.

Answer (score -1):

```
from kivy.app import App

 

from kivy.uix.camera import Camera

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.button import Button

 

class CameraExample(App):

 

    def build(self):

        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

       

        # Create a camera object

        self.cameraObject            = Camera(play=False)

        self.cameraObject.play       = True

        self.cameraObject.resolution = (300, 300) # Specify the resolution

       

        # Create a button for taking photograph

        self.camaraClick = Button(text="Take Photo")

        self.camaraClick.size_hint=(.5, .2)

        self.camaraClick.pos_hint={'x': .25, 'y':.75}

 

        # bind the button's on_press to onCameraClick

        self.camaraClick.bind(on_press=self.onCameraClick)

       

        # add camera and button to the layout

        layout.add_widget(self.cameraObject)

        layout.add_widget(self.camaraClick)

       

        # return the root widget

        return layout

 

    # Take the current frame of the video as the photo graph       

    def onCameraClick(self, *args):

        self.cameraObject.export_to_png('/kivyexamples/selfie.png')

       

       

# Start the Camera App

if __name__ == '__main__':

     CameraExample().run()
```

Comment: Found this post useful, give it an up vote and mark as correct answer.